# UTF-8 encoding in PHP

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have an issue encoding a text which I receive from Amazon MWS API.

With `utf8_decode` I get:

```
Arria Marcella: Le pied de momie - La Vénus d'Ille - Petite discussion avec une momie [Poche] [2011] Gautier, Théophile; M�rim�e, Prosper; Poe, Edgar Allan
```

you will notice the unreadable characters in the last words where it should actually be **Théophile Mérimée**.

With `iconv('UTF-8','ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', utf8_encode($text))`, I get:

```
Arria Marcella: Le pied de momie - La VÃ©nus d'Ille - Petite discussion avec une momie [Poche] [2011] Gautier, ThÃ©ophile; Mérimée, Prosper; Poe, Edgar Allan
```

The text is displayed in browser with `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8`

Original feed looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ListOrderItemsResponse xmlns="https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01">
    <ListOrderItemsResult>
        <AmazonOrderId>9731-58415164523441341-5544141772727</AmazonOrderId>
        <OrderItems>
            <OrderItem>
                <ASIN>2013229496</ASIN>
                <SellerSKU>MANUDSE-9782013229494-2013229496</SellerSKU>
                <OrderItemId>75452762426762624937</OrderItemId>
                <Title>Arria Marcella: Le pied de momie - La VÃ©nus d&#039;Ille - Petite discussion avec une momie [Poche] [2011] Gautier, ThÃ©ophile; Mérimée, Prosper; Poe, Edgar Allan</Title>
                <QuantityOrdered>1</QuantityOrdered>
                <QuantityShipped>0</QuantityShipped>
                <ItemPrice>
                    <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>10.00</Amount>
                </ItemPrice>
                <ShippingPrice>
                    <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>2.99</Amount>
                </ShippingPrice>
                <GiftWrapPrice>
                    <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </GiftWrapPrice>
                <ItemTax>
                    <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </ItemTax>
                <ShippingTax>
                    <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </ShippingTax>
                <GiftWrapTax>
                    <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </GiftWrapTax>
                <ShippingDiscount>
                    <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </ShippingDiscount>
                <PromotionDiscount>
                    <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
                    <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                </PromotionDiscount>
                <PromotionIds></PromotionIds>
                <ConditionNote>Prix d&#039;origine: 3.95 euros. Livraison sous 10 jours pour la France. Livraison sous 30 jours pour l&#039;Ã©tranger. Envoi de Bretagne. Envoi soignÃ© dans carton et bulle. English speakers welcome.F</ConditionNote>
                <ConditionId>New</ConditionId>
                <ConditionSubtypeId>New</ConditionSubtypeId>
            </OrderItem>
        </OrderItems>
    </ListOrderItemsResult>
    <ResponseMetadata>
        <RequestId>003452be-197c-4ade-8474-5efc5810240e</RequestId>
    </ResponseMetadata>
</ListOrderItemsResponse>
```

Any idea how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Considering the rest of the é characters display as expected, are you sure they were encoded correctly ( or are even the correct character ) in the the first place?

Comment: Are you positively sure that you application really uses ISO-8859-1? If so, why do you later send a `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8` header?

Comment: I used this content type because the end user expects an UTF-8 encoded output

Comment: So it's the API the one that's generating ISO-8859-1? Could you please edit the question and reflect clearly what the input and output encodings are?

Comment: Randomly applying encoding functions doesn't help anyone figure out what exactly is going on here. Can you provide a *hex dump* of the actual bytes you get from the API, and the text you expect it to represent? (Small relevant sample please, not pages and pages of binary data.)